# R2 live migration between Opteron 8354 and 2435

Tags: hyper-v

As per title, will the processor compatibility option allow a live migrate between an AMD Opeteron 2435 (dual proc, hex core) and an AMD Opteron 8354 (quad proc, quad core)? We are out of capacity and wish to use a newer dual socket server rather than an older (yet much more expensive) quad socket server in our cluster.

Comment: Just to clarify you REALLY mean VMWare right? "R2 Live Migration" is Hyper-V terminology but your tag says VMWare.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you'll be able to vmotion as both chips are generation 3 so any of the three EVC modes (gen 1, 2 & 3) will work.

Answer (score 0):

hmm since it is r2 I'm assuming hyper-v so yes the live migration will work just fine!

Comment: You *do* know, don't you, that live migration has some requirements as far as CPU compatibility between the two physical servers? That's what he was asking about, not about whether Hyper-V will support live migration.

Comment: yes I know all about proc compatibility issues with hyper-v.  and If they are in the same family of cpu's then live migration works fine.